# Read value from FloatProperty of PropertyGrid

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, propertygrid

Can somebody help me???
I have create this code with property grid and I don't read this value from float property "window" to the variables. This value is 100 in this case. Thx. J.

```
class LevyPanelNastaveni(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=-1):
        wx.Panel.__init__( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        bs = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_propertyGrid = pg.PropertyGrid(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 200,-1 ), wx.propgrid.PG_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        self.m_propertyGridItem = self.m_propertyGrid.Append(pg.PropertyCategory(u"Inlet value"))
        self.m_propertyGridItem1 = self.m_propertyGrid.Append(pg.FloatProperty("R1", value=100))
        bs.Add(self.m_propertyGrid, 0, wx.GROW+wx.ALL, 5)

        self.m_propertyGrid.

        self.SetSizerAndFit(bs)

        self.Layout()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the wxPython demo this is done like this:

pg.Append( wxpg.FloatProperty("Float",value=100.0) )

note that Value is Float and not an Int